# Missing Spacebars, fast-route on deployed Telescope install

Tags: node.js, deployment, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I have deployed a [Telescope](http://www.telesc.pe/) site to [my staging DigitalOcean droplet](http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/). The site works perfectly on my local machine, but I get several errors in Dev Tools when I try to pull up the deployed copy.

```
fast-route data found, but no collection exists for: settings a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: isAdminById is not defined a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:20
Exception in defer callback: ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
    at null._render (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:13:1470)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:26626)
    at http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:25734
    at Object.e._withCurrentView (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:28753)
    at http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:25692
    at e.Computation._compute (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:5:16650)
    at new e.Computation (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:5:15913)
    at Object.e.autorun (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:5:17886)
    at e.View.autorun (http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:25663)
    at http://staging.news.powerupgames.io/a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:10:26565 a66f3d03fa0387126449a4d3022ea653e4a8d4b4.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of undefined
```

The contents of the page never loads. It seems that some of the packages are missing, but the packages it's complaining about are listed in the [packages file](https://github.com/raddevon/gamedevnews/blob/newsletter-theme/.meteor/packages).

Not sure where to turn with this. As I said, I'm deploying to a DigitalOcean droplet. I use [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) for deployment. The deployment completes successfully without any errors. I've also tried deploying to [Modulus](https://modulus.io/). That deployment too finishes without errors but [exhibits the same problems](http://gamedev-news-30440.onmodulus.net/).